# Can I fetch Stack Overflow users by location in Stack Exchange API

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2, users

I read [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and I know that I can get users' locations but I have not seen anywhere about querying by location. Does that mean that it is not possible? If it is possible, how?

As an example, I want to do something like below:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/location=Lanka?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow
```

The above currently results in a `404` error.  Please add this capability.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible (short of fetching all users and filtering yourself). The API simply does not offer that query. For alternatives, see the Data Explorer (SEDE): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253728/295232

Comment: Yeah Im using that already and I tried to create simple app using this api to see/search top 100 users by country name instead of downloading csv and getting data from it. Thank you for saving my time!